# How to solve error - Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter ..."System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary"

Tags: powershell

How do I solve this error?

```
 curl ${OPENAI_API_BASE%/}/openai/deployments/try-davinci/completions?api-version=2022-06-01-preview -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken" -d '{ "prompt": "Tell me a funny story." }'
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:104
+ ... ersion=2022-06-01-preview -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Aut ...
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: You have to pass a dictionary `@{header1=value1}`

Comment: might have worked. can't confirm as now I have a new error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362418/powershell-a-positional-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-accepts-argument . Would you like to check this as well please?

Comment: You are sending an HTTP Request.  The HTTP header Content-Type of the request and the body has to be consistent.  You are getting an error because the server is expecting a dictionary and the content-type is application/json.  I think the json is not formatted correctly so when the data is deserialized it is not a dictionary.