# PowerShell - A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass a request/prompt to `azure openai resource` but getting error about positional parameter. How do I solve it?

```
 curl ${OPENAI_API_BASE%/}/openai/deployments/try-davinci/completions?api-version=2022-06-01-preview -H @{"Content-Type"="application/json";"Authorization"= "Bearer $accessToken"} -d '{ "prompt": "Tell me a funny story." }'
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '{ "prompt": "Tell me a funny story."
}'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl ${OPENAI_API_BASE%/}/openai/deployments/try-davinci/completions? ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: `curl` in PowerShell is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` which has different parameters. To use the actual binary, call it `curl.exe`.

Comment: I don't want to use the actual binary as that can affect other powershell specific things I am using.

Comment: I think there is no `-d` parameter for Invoke-WebRequest. If you are trying to post something to the server use `-Body` with the value as `@{"prompt": "value"}`